# RAID 5 options on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, raid

I'm given to understand that Disk Utility in macOS Big Sur does not support RAID options other than RAID 0 and RAID 1.  I've got a multi-drive enclosure that I'd like to setup for RAID 5.  Are there any other options for doing this?  I could do RAID 1 for multiple 2-drive pairs, but would prefer to have a single, large RAID 5 volume.  Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you aware of the fact that any RAID configuration handled by macOS will lead to increased data volume between your Mac and the drive enclosure (because data gets read from/written to several drives at once)?

Comment: Yup.  Well aware.

Comment: As you have discovered Big Sur (and all other versions of macOS) RAID only does RAID-0 and RAID-1. RAID-5 will require you to look for 3rd party apps. I gather SoftRAID is good but I have never used it. There are likely others.

Comment: @SteveChambers fixed a typo.  I meant to say Big Sur supported RAID0 and RAID1, not RAID5.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you use a hardware device that is specifically designed for RAID and runs it own OS/Software to handle its RAID.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS's built-in RAID handling is limited. For decent RAID support, I recommend SoftRAID, which does RAID 0, 1, 4, 5 and '1+0'.

https://www.softraid.com

They've recently discontinued their 'Lite' version, and so it's a little more expensive than it was: but there's not much else.